# React Hooks getting usestate value from child component into parent component? Or better way to do this?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-context

Im using react hooks to create a multi-select component, that generates sliders for each selection (using material-ui). Once a user makes their selections I'm generating an individual slider for each selection using map. Each slider component has its own instance of useState to keep track of the value of the slider. Im passing a nodeid as a key to the component and would like to have an array of [nodeid, valueFromSlider] for each slider returned. For example: if a user makes 3 selections and then calls 'update feedback scores' button, returned values should be `[[nodeid, valueFromSlider], [nodeid, valueFromSlider], [nodeid, valueFromSlider]]`.

What is the best way for my parent component to know what each individual sliders state is? is there a way to call component by id? Should i be usings forms or something? first time really using hooks since switching from redux.

Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
const NodeSlider = (props) => {
  const { node, nodeId } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(5);
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
        {node.display_name}
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        step={1}
        marks
        min={-10}
        max={10}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        defaultValue={5}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const TunerSlider = (props) => {
  const { sliders } = props;
  const [feedbackArray, setFeedbackArray] = useState(null);
  console.log('sliders', sliders);
  const createFeedbackArray = () => {
    // FIGURE THIS OUT? use this to call setfeedback array with value from node slider? 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {sliders.map((slider) => (
        <NodeSlider
          key={slider.node_id}
          node={slider}
          nodeId={slider.node_id}
        />
      ))}
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => createFeedbackArray()}
      >
        Update Feedback Scores
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

const TunerSearch = ({ nodeData }) => {
  const [searchValues, setSearchValues] = useState(null);
  const [sliderValues, setSliderValues] = useState(null);

  const generateSlider = () => {
    setSliderValues(searchValues);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Tuner Search</div>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={nodeData}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.display_name}
        filterSelectedOptions
        onChange={(event, value) => setSearchValues(value)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="select nodes"
            placeholder="add more nodes"
          />
        )}
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => generateSlider()}
      >
        Generate Node Sliders
      </Button>
      {sliderValues ? <TunerSlider sliders={sliderValues} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TunerSearch;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to move the states to the highest common parent.
Then you can define your function that will track your feedback in the parent component and then share them with the children component(s).

Here is an example of how I would approach this:

[image: Edit trusting-bartik-sstkf]